# What's the best way to eliminate/deter rats from a garden without harming squirrels?

Tags: pest-control, pests

I have a friend who wants to plant a garden were she has moved, but she has a huge rat problem and is afraid that if she plants a garden they will be a nuisance. She is afraid of using poison or conventional traps because she also has a few families of squirrels that live in her yard and around her. She wants to get rid of the rats (or at least deter them) without hurting or harming the squirrels. We are trying to come up with a solution before spring so we can get a garden well established by May. If anyone has any experience or suggestions we'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Are the rats huge I.e. Squirrel size, or huge in number? Are there fresh water sources near by. Are there neighbors? What's the native fox population?

Comment: I would think if planning a food type garden your neighbor would be worried about the squirrels eating it too.

Comment: So there is a huge number of rats. There is a small creak nearby She thinks that they may be coming from there. The place where she is, is pretty developed she has never seen any foxes around there. She has many neghbors

Comment: How about getting some pet snakes?

Answer (score 1):

I, too, had a squirrel and rat problem.  The only thing that worked was building a walk-in cage.  I built mine out of pvc, 19g vinyl covered hardware cloth, zip ties, and a few hinges for the door.  Solved the problem.  If you don't want to use pvc,  you could always hire a carpenter to build one out of wood.